# What determines whether a package will compile from source and how to change?

Tags: r, cran

The symptom I can see is that when `install.packages("dplyr")` is run from one mac, it installs almost instantly, whereas the exact same command from another macbook takes ~5 minutes to install, and has a lot (100s of lines) of R console output

I presume the latter is compiling? Where can I find (and change) this default setting?

Here is a sample of the console output

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Collector.cpp -o Collector.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c CollectorGuess.cpp -o CollectorGuess.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Iconv.cpp -o Iconv.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c LocaleInfo.cpp -o LocaleInfo.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Reader.cpp -o Reader.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Source.cpp -o Source.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Tokenizer.cpp -o Tokenizer.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c TokenizerDelim.cpp -o TokenizerDelim.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c TokenizerFwf.cpp -o TokenizerFwf.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c TokenizerWs.cpp -o TokenizerWs.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c connection.cpp -o connection.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c datetime.cpp -o datetime.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c grisu3.c -o grisu3.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c localtime.c -o localtime.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c parse.cpp -o parse.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c read.cpp -o read.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"  -I. -Ircon -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c type_convert.cpp -o type_convert.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I"/us
```

Comment: In some OS's (Windows, OS X) there are binary versions of the package on CRAN. If not it will have to compile the source.

Comment: There is a section `Binary packages` in the help page for `install.packages`. It explains the steps the function takes before going one way or the other.